# How to perform looped queries in transactions properly with node.js, mssql and msnodesqlv8

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, angular

I am attempting to do what I've previously done in c# and asp.net webforms and execute a number of insert stored procedures, some of which are in loops, in a transaction.  I am now trying to do so in my angular application through node.js with the mssql package.  What I have so far is as follows.

```
    //Insert Change Record
router.post('/insertChange', (req, res) => {
    const transaction = new sql.Transaction(conn);

    transaction.begin(err => {
        let rolledBack = false;
        transaction.on('rollback', aborted => {
            rolledBack = true;
        })
        const request = new sql.Request(transaction);
        request.input('ChangeTitle', req.body.changeTitle);
        request.input('TypeId', req.body.typeId);
        request.input('DateSubmitted', req.body.dateSubmitted);
        request.input('TargetDate', req.body.targetProductionDate);

        request.input('ChangeSponsor', req.body.changeSponsor);
        request.input('UATDate', req.body.dateReadyUAT);
        request.input('ChangeSponsorEmail', req.body.changeSponsorEmail);
        request.input('ClarityId', req.body.clarityId);
        request.input('ChangeDescription', req.body.changeDescription);

        request.input('ComponentName', req.body.componentName);
        request.input('ComponentDescription', req.body.componentDescription);

        request.input('ReasonForChange', req.body.reasonForChange);
        request.input('ComponentREplacing', req.body.componentReplacing);
        request.input('DependentChange', req.body.dependentChange);

        request.input('InstallOption', req.body.installOption);
        request.input('RebootRequired', req.body.rebootRequired);
        request.input('UserIntervention', req.body.userIntervention);
        request.input('Activation', req.body.activation);

        request.input('ContingencyPlan', req.body.contingencyPlan);
        request.input('AdditionalInformation', req.body.additionalInformation);

        request.input('PerformanceImpact', req.body.applicationPerformance);
        request.input('IsPCoERequired', req.body.pcoeTesting);
        request.input('IsCanadianRetailBranch', req.body.pbsTesting);

        request.input('BusinessAppImpact', req.body.businessApplication);
        request.input('NetworkImpact', req.body.networkPerformance);
        request.input('NewInfrastructure', req.body.newInfrastructure);
        request.input('LogonTime', req.body.logonTime);
        request.input('AdditionalTechnicalInformation', req.body.additionalAssessmentInfo);

        request.input('IsProdIssue', req.body.isProdIssue);
        request.input('ProdIssue', req.body.productionIssue);
        request.input('ProdIncidentNum', req.body.incidentNumbers);
        request.input('IsMajorChange', req.body.isMajorChange);
        request.input('HasRequiredTesting', req.body.hasRequiredTesting);
        request.input('HasPackageSubmit', req.body.hasPackageSubmit);
        request.input('SignOffETA', req.body.signoffETA);
        request.input('SpecificTesting', req.body.specificTesting);
        request.input('SpecificPilot', req.body.specificPilot);
        request.input('PilotInfo', req.body.pilotTransits);

        request.input('UserChanges', req.body.userDifferences);
        request.input('ServiceDeskProcedure', req.body.procedureSupport);
        request.input('SupportCallFlowId', req.body.supportCallFlow);

        request.input('OverallChangeStatus', 1);

        let changeId = request.output('changeId', sql.Int);

        request.execute('dbo.InsertChange').then(function (result) {
            console.dir(result);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.dir(err);
        });

        async.each(
            req.body.changeType
            ,function iterator(item, next) {
            const requestCT = new sql.Request(transaction);
            requestCT.input('ChangeId', changeId);
            requestCT.input('TypeOfChangeId', item.typeOfChangeId);
            requestCT.input('Description', item.description);
            requestCT.execute('dbo.InsertTypeOfChange').then(function (result) {
                console.dir(result);
                next();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.dir(err);
            });
        })
        async.each(
            req.body.serviceImpacted
            ,function iterator(item, next) {
            const requestSI = new sql.Request(transaction);
            requestSI.input('ChangeId', changeId);
            requestSI.input('ServicesImpactedId', item.serviceImpactedId);
            requestSI.execute('dbo.InsertImpactedService').then(function (result) {
                console.dir(result);
                next();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.dir(err);
            });
        })
        async.each(
            req.body.businessImpacted
            ,function iterator(item, next) {
            const requestBI = new sql.Request(transaction);
            requestBI.input('ChangeId', changeId);
            requestBI.input('BusinessImpactedId', item.businessImpactedId);
            requestBI.execute('dbo.InsertImpactedBusiness').then(function (result) {
                console.dir(result);
                next();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.dir(err);
            });
        })
        async.each(
            req.body.criticalApp
            ,function iterator(item, next) {
            const requestCA = new sql.Request(transaction);
            requestCA.input('ChangeId', changeId);
            requestCA.input('CriticalBankingId', item.criticalId);
            requestCA.input('Description', item.description);
            requestCA.execute('dbo.InsertCriticalBankingApp').then(function (result) {
                console.dir(result);
                next();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.dir(err);
            });
        })
        async.each(
            req.body.testStages
            ,function iterator(item, next) {
            const requestTS = new sql.Request(transaction);
            requestTS.input('ChangeId', changeId);
            requestTS.input('TestStageId', item.testStageId);
            requestTS.input('TestDate', item.testDate);
            requestTS.input('Description', item.description);
            requestTS.execute('dbo.InsertChangeTest').then(function (result) {
                console.dir(result);
                next();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.dir(err);
            });
        })

        if (err) {
            if (!rolledBack) {
                transaction.rollback(err => {
                    console.dir(err);
                    // ... error checks
                })
            }
        } else {
            transaction.commit(err => {
                console.dir(err);
                // ... error checks

            })
        }
    })
});
```

There really isn't a heck of a lot of material online anywhere for processing transactions with stored procedures, and even less for big transactions like this.  But the error I'm getting is the following multiple times in my terminal log.

```
{ TransactionError: Can't acquire connection for the request. There is another request in progress.
at Transaction.acquire (C:\Users\Redirection\meecd26\Documents\GitRepo\td-angular-starter\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:740:30)
at Immediate._query.err [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\Redirection\meecd26\Documents\GitRepo\td-angular-starter\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8.js:417:19)
at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5) code: 'EREQINPROG', name: 'TransactionError' }
```

This certainly suggests that I'm performing the transaction improperly.

Would someone be able to help guide me as to how I can improve and fix this?

Edit: Made changes to my code to reflect what I found [here](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/113), as well as a few changes to my first insert.  While my first insert does work, I'm still getting the repeated errors above, so now I know my problems are with how I'm implementing the inserts inside of loops.  Is there a way I can close the connection upon each insert?  Would that be the approach I should try and take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it working, and although my understanding of how everything works admittedly hasn't improved much at all, I can at least post what I have in hopes of others hopefully finding it helpful.

```
router.post('/insertChange', (req, res) => {
console.log("Beginning of POST, before initializing transaction");

let changeId;
let mainInsert = false;

beginTransaction(function (err, rollback, transaction) {
    if (err) {
        // return cb(err);
    }
    let request = new sql.Request(transaction);
    // request.verbose = true;
    request.input('ChangeTitle', req.body.ChangeTitle);
    request.input('TypeId', req.body.TypeId);
    request.input('DateSubmitted', req.body.DateSubmitted);
    request.input('TargetDate', req.body.TargetDate);

    request.input('ChangeSponsor', req.body.ChangeSponsor);
    request.input('UATDate', req.body.UATDate);
    request.input('ChangeSponsorEmail', req.body.ChangeSponsorEmail);
    request.input('ClarityId', req.body.ClarityId);
    request.input('ChangeDescription', req.body.ChangeDescription);

    request.input('ComponentName', req.body.ComponentName);
    request.input('ComponentDescription', req.body.ComponentDescription);

    request.input('ReasonForChange', req.body.ReasonForChange);
    request.input('ComponentReplacing', req.body.ComponentReplacing);
    request.input('DependentChange', req.body.DependentChange);

    request.input('InstallOption', req.body.InstallOption);
    request.input('RebootRequired', req.body.RebootRequired);
    request.input('UserIntervention', req.body.UserIntervention);
    request.input('Activation', req.body.Activation);

    request.input('ContingencyPlan', req.body.ContingencyPlan);
    request.input('AdditionalInformation', req.body.AdditionalInformation);

    request.input('PerformanceImpact', req.body.PerformanceImpact);
    request.input('IsPCoERequired', req.body.IsPCoERequired);
    request.input('IsCanadianRetailBranch', req.body.IsCanadianRetailBranch);

    request.input('BusinessAppImpact', req.body.BusinessAppImpact);
    request.input('NetworkImpact', req.body.NetworkImpact);
    request.input('NewInfrastructure', req.body.NewInfrastructure);
    request.input('LogonTime', req.body.LogonTime);
    request.input('AdditionalTechnicalInformation', req.body.AdditionalTechnicalInformation);

    request.input('IsProdIssue', req.body.IsProdIssue);
    request.input('ProdIssue', req.body.ProdIssue);
    request.input('ProdIncidentNum', req.body.ProdIncidentNum);
    request.input('IsMajorChange', req.body.IsMajorChange);
    request.input('HasRequiredTesting', req.body.HasRequiredTesting);
    request.input('HasPackageSubmit', req.body.HasPackageSubmit);
    request.input('SignOffETA', req.body.SignOffETA);
    request.input('SpecificTesting', req.body.SpecificTesting);
    request.input('SpecificPilot', req.body.SpecificPilot);
    request.input('PilotInfo', req.body.PilotInfo);

    request.input('UserChanges', req.body.UserChanges);
    request.input('ServiceDeskProcedure', req.body.ServiceDeskProcedure);
    request.input('SupportCallFlowId', req.body.SupportCallFlowId);

    request.input('OverallChangeStatus', 1);

    request.output('changeId', sql.Int);

    request.execute('dbo.InsertChange', function (err, callback) {
        if (err) {
            console.dir(err);
            rollback(err);
            res.status(400).send("Failed to submit change form.");

        } else {
            mainInsert = true;
        }

        if (callback) {
            changeId = +callback.returnValue;
        }

        if (mainInsert) {
            async.each(
                req.body.changeType, function iterator(item, next) {
                    request = new sql.Request(transaction);
                    request.input('ChangeId', changeId);
                    request.input('TypeOfChangeId', item.typeOfChangeId);
                    request.input('Description', item.description);
                    request.execute('dbo.InsertTypeOfChange', function (err, callback) {
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        console.dir(callback);
                        next();
                    })
                }, function fin(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        rollback(err);
                        return; //done
                    }
                })
            async.each(
                req.body.serviceImpacted, function iterator(item, next) {
                    request = new sql.Request(transaction);
                    request.input('ChangeId', changeId);
                    request.input('ServicesImpactedId', item.serviceImpactedId);
                    request.execute('dbo.InsertImpactedService', function (err, callback) {
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        console.dir(callback);
                        next();
                    })
                }, function fin(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        rollback(err);
                        return; //done
                    }
                })
            async.each(
                req.body.businessImpacted, function iterator(item, next) {
                    request = new sql.Request(transaction);
                    request.input('ChangeId', changeId);
                    request.input('BusinessImpactedId', item.businessImpactedId);
                    request.execute('dbo.InsertImpactedBusiness', function (err, callback) {
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        console.dir(callback);
                        next();
                    })
                }, function fin(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        rollback(err);
                        return; //done
                    }
                })
            async.each(
                req.body.criticalApp, function iterator(item, next) {
                    request = new sql.Request(transaction);
                    request.input('ChangeId', changeId);
                    request.input('CriticalBankingId', item.criticalId);
                    request.input('Description', item.description);
                    request.execute('dbo.InsertCriticalBankingApp', function (err, callback) {
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        console.dir(callback);
                        next();
                    })
                }, function fin(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        rollback(err);
                        return; //done
                    }
                })
            async.each(
                req.body.testStages, function iterator(item, next) {
                    request = new sql.Request(transaction);
                    request.input('ChangeId', changeId);
                    request.input('TestStageId', item.testStageId);
                    request.input('TestDate', item.testDate);
                    request.input('Description', item.description);
                    request.execute('dbo.InsertChangeTest', function (err, callback) {
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        console.dir(callback);
                        next();
                    })
                }, function fin(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        rollback(err);
                        return; //done
                    }
                    else {
                        transaction.commit(function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error('Transaction commit error: ', err);
                                res.status(400).send("Failed to submit change form.");
                            } else {
                                console.error('Transaction commit success');
                                res.send({ "Response": "Success", "Message": "Change form successfully submitted." });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
        }
    });
})
});
```

Comment: Have you in the end found out more about how to properly handle transactions? I'm using promises instead of async and am getting the same error, so trying to find proper documentation about it.

Comment: I'm afraid I promptly moved on to the rest of the project and haven't had much time to review this.  Have you posted a question on here with your situation?  Good luck on finding documentation and support, it's borderline non-existent.

Comment: I havent posted a question yet, but pretty much same like you moved on to next pressing issues, but i'll for sure have to revisit this code soon so hoping that by that time ill have a proper solution. Thanks for your response.